# Laravel custom strings helper file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-helper

I created an Artisan command file which handles strings in different encodings.

I needed to implement a `mb_str_pad` function (and found [this one](https://gist.github.com/nebiros/226350)).

I created a helper file `app/Library/Helpers/StringHelper.php`:

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('mb_str_pad')) {
    function mb_str_pad() {
        :
        :
    }
}
```

Then I added it to `composer.json` file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Library/Helpers/StringHelper.php" // <-- Here
    ]
},
```

And run `composer dump-autoload`.

**When I try to run the command (`php artisan mytasks:generate`) I get this error:**

```
Call to undefined function App\Console\Commands\mb_str_pad()
```

**2nd try:**
I also tried to add a service with:

```
php artisan make:provider StringHelperServiceProvider
```

In the `register()` function I put:

```
require_once app_path('Library/Helpers/StringHelper.php');
```

And in `app.php` added to `providers` array:

```
App\Providers\StringHelperServiceProvider::class,
```

But I get the same error.

=========================== Edit ======================

I have no good explanation for it, but now the same code works fine.

The only thing I did was to test my function with Tinker:

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> mb_str_pad("Hello", 10);
=> "Hello     "
>>> mb_str_pad("Hello", 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
=> "     Hello"
>>> mb_str_pad("Helló", 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
=> "     Helló"
>>>
```

**I leave this question in case it will help somebody.**

Answer (score 1):

After creating the helper file you need to add the pathe of it to `composer.json` in `files` section under `autoload`. Then you should be able to use your helper function like any other framework helper functions.

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helper.php"
    ],
},
```

After updating `composer.json` run `composer dumpautoload`.

Be sure to check whether function already exist before declaring

```
if (!function_exists('mb_str_pad')) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Did you run a `composer dumpautoload` after adding that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining the helper file in your `composer.json`, you can also require it in your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::register()` method:

```
$filenames = glob(app_path('Library/Helpers/*.php'));
if ($filenames !== false && is_iterable($filenames)) {
    foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
       require_once $filename;
    }
}
```